# React infinite scroll component is not working

Tags: next.js

I am using 'React infinite scroll component' to implement the infinite scroll. It is always showing two recods. Looks like next={fetchData} is not calling on scroll. Because I am new to next js so unable to debug the problem

I am using following code to read blog folder:

```
const fs = require('fs');  

export default async function handler(req, res) 
{
  let blogs = [];
  const count = req.query.count;
  try 
  {
    let files=  fs.readdirSync('blogdata');
    
    files.forEach((file,index)=>
    {
      
      if( count === undefined || count>index)
      {
        let content =  fs.readFileSync('blogdata/'+file,'utf-8');
        blogs.push(JSON.parse(content));
      }
    });
    res.status(200).json(blogs)
  }
  catch(err)
  {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

I am using following code for fron end:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import styles from "@/styles/Blogs.module.css";
import Link from "next/link";
import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroll-component";

export default function Blogs() {
  const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([]);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(2);

  function createMarkup(content) {
    return { __html: content };
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/blogs?count=${count}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        setBlogs(json);
        setCount(count + 2);
      });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <InfiniteScroll
        dataLength={100}
        next={fetchData}
        hasMore={true}
        loader={<h4>Loading...</h4>}
        endMessage={
          <p style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
            <b>Yay! You have seen it all</b>
          </p>
        }
      >
        {blogs.length > 0 ? (
          <div className="container ">
            <h2 className={styles.h2}>Blogs</h2>
            <ul className={styles.ul}>
              {blogs.map((blog, index) => (
                <li key={index} className={styles.li}>
                  <Link href={`blog/${blog.slug}`} className={styles.title}>
                    {blog.title}
                  </Link>
                  <p
                    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(
                      blog.content.substring(0, 399)
                    )}
                  ></p>
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <p className="container blogs">Loading blogs</p>
        )}
      </InfiniteScroll>
    </>
  );
}
```

I have used the following code too:

```
const fetchData = async () => {
  fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/blogs?count=${count}`)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((json) => {
        setBlogs([...blogs, ...json]);
        setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 2);
    });
};
```

Comment: I have the same problem! Any solutions yet?